# Use DatabaseCallback when executing a sqlite3_stmt

Tags: c++, sql, database, sqlite, parameterized-query

I am implementing parameter queries for sqlite in C++ and I want to have the DatabaseCallback updated when I execute.  I know it is possible when your query is a string but is it possible when it is a sqlite3_stmt?
Note: sql is my select string

```
            DatabaseCallback* pCallback;
            sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
            const char *pzTest;
            int selectCommand = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database_, sql.c_str(), strlen(sql.c_str()), &stmt, &pzTest);

            if(selectCommand == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                //Add the parameter values
                int parameterPosition = 1;

                if(parameters.size() > 0)
                {
                    size_t count = parameters.size();
                    for(string str : parameters)
                    {
                        int returncode = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt,parameterPosition, str.c_str(), strlen(str.c_str()),SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                        parameterPosition++;
                    }

                }
            }

            sqlite3_step(stmt);
            sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

Comment: What callback? Do you mean that of `sqlite3_exec`?

Comment: Yes.  I want to implement sqlite3_exec for the callback functionality except with a sqlite3_stmt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to call [sqlite3_step](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html) multiple times, and get the values with the [sqlite3_column_*](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html) functions in each step.

If you really want to have the same behaviour as `sqlite3_exec`, just copy [its implementation](http://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/artifact/0df0b1550b9cc1f58229644735e317ac89131f12).